# Adding two tuples in F#

Tags: f#, tuples

Trying to understand tuples in F#..

Current thought process

```
let add tuples a b = 
let a = (_,_)
let b= (_,_)
(a+b)
```

this won't work due to "_" being invalid for this case so then I thought to try

```
let add tuples a b =
let a = (c,d)
let b = (e,f)
fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b;;
```

this won't work because c,d,e,&f are not known variables. In java I would traditionally just initialize that variable so it can be used but in F# that seems a bit funky `let a= int` *not even sure if that would work anyways*

any help on trying to fix my thought process would be appreciated. Thanks

edit:

expected result

a (1,3)
b (2,4)
return (3,7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways of accessing elements from a tuple and your code seems to be confusing them. First, you can use `fst` and `snd` on two-element tuples. You actually have this right, but you need to remove other unnecessary lines - `a` and `b` are tuples, so you can write just:

```
let add a b =
  fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b
```

The other option is to use pattern matching. To do this, you need to assing a tuple value, i.e. `a` or `b` to a pattern that defines new variables like `(c, d)`. Doing the above using pattern matching looks like this:

```
let add a b =
  let (a1, a2) = a
  let (b1, b2) = b
  a1 + b1, a2 + b2
```

Patterns can appear in stand-alone `let` bindings like above, but you can also use them directly in the arguments of a function - so you can shorted this to:

```
let add (a1, a2) (b1, b2) = 
  a1 + b1, a2 + b2
```

Comment: Thank you! I am migrating from Java to F# and the lack of declarations needed has been confusing but this helps clear some things up.

Comment: @huffola You may find it easier if you add explicit type signatures to your function. ie `let add (a:int)  (b:int) : int*int = fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b` You can always remove them later for style or because they restrict usage.